# Regarding a memory leak issue

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development. I have a memory leak issue in the following code. If anyone knows why it's happening please help me.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier1;
    if(universalApp==2)
    {
    CellIdentifier1 = @"CustomThumbImageTableCell_iphone";
    cell = [[[CustomThumbImageTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];

        //NSLog(@">>>>> Creating image >>>>>>>>");
    cell.thumbImageView = [[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 83, 101)];


    [imgViewArray addObject:cell.thumbImageView];
    [cell.thumbImageView release];  

}
```

Comment: try using `build and analyse`

Comment: yes.i did that.its getting leaked at" cell.thumbImageView = [[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 83, 101)];

"

Comment: but i released that object also..

Comment: Did you try autoreleasing the CustomImageView in the following line like this? `cell.thumbImageView = [[[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 83, 101)] autorelease];`

Comment: just a pointer... addObject also allocates memory...

Comment: @user599561 when is imgViewArray deallocated? As you know, the retain count of an object added to NSMutableArray is increated by 1.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the @property flag for cell.thumbImageView? Are you using retain or copy for it?

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, use auto release pool,

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {


NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

...
cell.thumbImageView = [[[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 83, 101)] autorelease];
...

[pool release];
}
```

And check imgViewArray, as you know, the retain count of an object added to an NSMutableArray is increased by 1.

Comment: thanks for ur answer.i tried this also but getting the memory leak at the same place.

Comment: I modified my answer and left a comment.